# EF Core: How to best get average value in a model of a related model

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I've got a Blazor Server App using the Entity Framework (EF Core).

I use a code first approach with two models, `Entry` and `Target`.

Each entry has a target. So a target can have more than one entry pointing to it.

The model for the `Target` looks like this:

```
public class Target
  {
    public string TargetId { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Target")]
    public List<Entry> Entries { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public double AverageEntryRating => Entries != null ? Entries.Where(e => e.Rating > 0).Select(e => e.Rating).Average() : 0;
  }
```

An entry can have a rating, the model `Entry` looks like this:

```
public class Entry
  {
    public string EntryId { get; set; }
    
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string TargetId {get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TargetId")]
    public Target Target { get; set; }    
  }
```

As you can see in my `Target` model, I would like to know for each `Target`, what the average rating for it is, based on the average of all entries that point to the `Target` - that's why there is this (`NotMapped`) property in the target:

```
public double AverageEntryRating => Entries != null ? Entries.Where(e => e.Rating > 0).Select(e => e.Rating).Average() : 0;
```

But this does (of course) not always work, as the Entries of the target are not guaranteed to be loaded at the time the property is accessed.

I tried to solve it differently, for example to have a method in my TargetService, where I can pass in a targetId and gives me the result:

```
 public double GetTargetMedianEntryRating(string targetId) {
        var median = _context.Entries
            .Where(e => e.TargetId == targetId && e.Rating > 0)
            .Select(e => e.Rating)
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
            .Average();
        return median;
    }
```

But when I list out my targets in a table and then in a cell want to display this value (passing in the current targetId of the foreach loop) I get a concurrency exception, as the database context is used in multiple threads (I guess one from looping through the rows/targets and one other from getting the average value)... so this leads me into new troubles.

Personally I would prefer to work with the `AverageEntryRating` property on the `Target` model, as it seems natural to me and it would also be convenient to access the value just like this.

But how would I make sure, that the entries are loaded, when I access this property. Or is this not a good approach because this would mean I would have to load Entries anyway for all the targets which would lead to performance degradation? If yes, what would be a good way to get to the average/median value?

Comment: When do you plan to use AverageEntryRating? If just for one API Call, you do not need that property in Model.

Comment: I need it, when I loop over the targets, to place the properties of the target in a table, I want to also display the average entry rating in a column of the table.

Comment: There is the difference how you display data and how it is stored. If you need to display, we can create effective query which prepare data for displaying. It will be another class which has additionally calculated `AverageEntryRating` value.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You mean I should create another model with this property to calculate the value and then use that for display the value? Isn't this somehow similar to my example with the TargetService, where I also have a special query to fetch my value but will lead me to the concurrency error?

Comment: How about making changing  where AverageEntryRating calculation is being made? It makes an infinite loop because everytime you want to access a Target it loads its entries and to calculate the entries' AverageEntryRating it goes for its targets again... 
So if I were you I would do that calculation in db level or every time target is being created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options I could think of, and it depends on you situation what to do. There might be more alternatives, but at least I hope that this can give you some options you hadn't considered.

**Have a BaseQuery extension method that always include all Entries**

You could make sure of doing `.Include(x => x.Entries)` whenever you are querying for `Target`. You can even create an extension method of the database context called something like `TargetBaseQuery()` that includes all necessary relationship whenever you use it. Then you will be sure that the `Entries` List of each Target will be loaded when you access the property `AverageEntryRating`.

The downside will be a performance hit, since every time you load a Target you will need to load all its entries... and that's for every Target you query.
However, if you need to get it working fast, this would be probably the easiest. The pragmatic approach would be to do this, measure the performance hit, and if it is too slow then try something else, instead of doing premature optimization. The risk of course would be that it might work fast now, but it might scale badly in the future. So it's up to you to decide.

Another thing to consider would be to not Include the Entries every single time, but only in those places where you know you need the average. It might however become a maintainability issue.

**Have a different model and service method to calculate the TargetStats**

You could create another class Model that stores the related data of a `Target`, but it's not persisted in the database. For example:

```
public class TargetStats
  {    
    public Target Target { get; set; }

    public double AverageEntryRating { get; set; }
  }
```

Then in your service you could have a method ish like this ***(haven't tested, so it might not work as is, but you get the idea)***:

```
public List<TargetStats> GetTargetStats() {
        var targetStats = _context.Target
            .Include(x => x.Entries)
            .Select(x => new TargetStats 
            {
              Target = x, 
              AverageEntryRatings = x.Entries.Where(e => e.Rating > 0).Select(e => e.Rating).Average(),
            })
            .ToList()

        return targetStats;
    }
```

The only advantage of this is that you don't have to degrade the performance of all Target related queries, but only of those that requires the average rating.
But this query in particular might still be slow. What you could do to further tweak it, is write raw SQL instead of LINQ or have a view in the database that you can query.

**Store and update the Target's average rating as a column**

Probably the best you could do to keep the code clean and have good performance while reading, is to store the average as a column in the Target table. This will move the performance cost of the calculation to the saving/updating of a Target or its related Entries, but the readings will be super fast since the data is already available. If the readings happen way more often than the updates, then it's probably worth doing it.

You could take a look at [EF Core docs on perfomance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/modeling-for-performance#update-cache-columns-when-inputs-change), since they talk a little bit about the different perfomance tunning alternatives.

Comment: I am now loading the average column aferter I fetched the targets. Also I had some issue with the context (concurrency) but this could be solved by using a DB context factory and making sure I use a different context for fetching the averages, so that there is no conflict when I update an item in the meantime.

Comment: @Patric glad to hear that you managed to figure it out.